# How to create a two string array from a sequence of key-value pairs (tuple) in swift

Tags: ios, dictionary, key-value, swift4

I have two string array and it's define following so how to create a dictionary from a sequence of key-value pairs.

```
let cityNames = ["Riyadh", "Mecca", "Sultanah", "Buraydah", "Al Qarah"]
let nearestDistances = [84.24, 41.37, 45.37, 57.96, 78.78]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, since Xcode 9, the *Swift Standard Library* provides a handy [`Dictionary` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init) for such cases:

```swift
init<S>(uniqueKeysWithValues keysAndValues: S) 
where S: Sequence, S.Element == (Key, Value)
```

> Creates a new dictionary from the *key-value* pairs in the given sequence.

This might be difficult to read if aren't too familiar with Swift generics ;) Nevertheless, the usage is pretty straightforward:

```swift
let cityNames = ["Riyadh", "Mecca", "Sultanah", "Buraydah", "Al Qarah"]
let nearestDistances = [84.24, 41.37, 45.37, 57.96, 78.78]

let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(cityNames, nearestDistances))
print(dict)
```

prints:

```swift
[  
  "Buraydah": 57.96, 
  "Al Qarah": 78.78, 
  "Mecca":    41.37, 
  "Riyadh":   84.24, 
  "Sultanah": 45.37
]
```

Finally, the resulting dictionary type is what you would expect:

```
print(type(of: dict)) // Dictionary<String, Double>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `zip` them up and combine them in a loop

```
var dictionary = [String: Double]()

for (city, distance) in zip(cityNames, nearestDistances){
    dictionary[city] = distance
}
```

Better yet, you can make a nice extension for it:

```
extension Dictionary{
    init(keys: [Key], values: [Value]){
        self.init()
        for (key, value) in zip(keys, values){
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}

let dictionary = Dictionary<String, Double>(keys: cityNames, values: nearestDistances)
```

Comment: You could also use the new initializers: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init / https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2892961-init (depending if the keys are unique or not)